# Fast display of waveform in C/C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, data-structures

I'm interested in implementing an audio editor in C or C++ on Windows and Linux. I can't figure out how to display the waveform quickly enough in its fully zoomed out view. I'm not looking for information about fast frame buffer techniques. This is a question about algorithms and data-structures to efficiently determine what to display.

Say I want to be able to edit a 5 channel, 48 KHz, 24-bit sound that is 2 hours long. That's 5 gigabytes of sample data. I want to be able to zoom out from one-pixel-per-sample all the way until all the sample data is visible at once. I want the application to feel responsive, even on a slow machine, like, for arguments sake, a 1 GHz Atom. When I say responsive, I'd like the GUI updates to generally occur within 1/30th of a second of the user input.

A naive implementation would scan every sample in the whole waveform when deciding what to render for the fully zoomed-out view - it needs to find the max and min sample values for all samples "covered" by each pixel width of the display. I wrote a simple app to test the speed of this approach. I tested with a 1 hour long, mono, 16-bit, 44.1 KHz sample on my 2015 3.5 GHz Xeon. It takes 0.12 seconds. This is hundreds of times too slow.

You can imagine maintaining a cache of zoomed out data, but I can't see how to avoid having to recalculate the entire cache after most inserts or deletes. It feels like there must be a better way.

Here's a diagram showing what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is how the display in most currently available audio editors works. Users are likely to expect this behaviour. I tested with Audacity, and it works this way (although it also shows something like the mean of the samples in a lighter colour too). It can handle arbitrary inserts into large sounds, seemingly instantly. I'm not going to read the 75 megabytes of source code to find out how it does it.

**EDIT:**

Various people have suggested schemes that involve only considering a subset of the samples when showing the zoomed out view. I've come to the conclusion that I don't want to do that because it loses too much useful information. For example, including all the samples is important if you are looking for a glitch in the sound, like a click in a vinyl conversion. In the worst case, if the glitch is only one sample long, I still want a guarantee that it is shown in the fully zoomed out view.

Comment: Downsampling! Downsampling! 1/30th of a second is a dream on an old machine but you can get good results with better hardware. Also remember that graphics and IO will be the slow part unless you put a lot of care. Uncompressed wave can be seek to read 1 sample each n (inaccurate but responsive) and then in background read and downsample. Cache after everything else is done and accept you will not have performance you want. It's not ONE algorithm or ONE data structure but a bunch of techniques to give that *impression*.

Comment: What do you mean by downsampling? By what I understand from the term, if I downsample a 20 KHz squarewave, I get a DC signal. Whereas the display should still show a full amplitude signal. I can see that reading 1 in every n samples to get an inaccurate but responsive display is a possible answer to my original question. BTW, I can already draw the data quickly to the screen. I just draw all the lines into a bitmap in RAM and then blit the whole thing to the screen.

Comment: Any explanation for the down votes?

Comment: How are you updating the GUI?  What GUI framework are you using?

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded?  For example, is one thread handling the input and another is drawing?

Comment: Have you employed double or multiple buffering?  For example, input data is written to one buffer while the GUI is accessing another buffer for drawing.

Comment: You may want to have the GUI window read the data versus having another entity post the data to the GUI.

Comment: Are you taking advantage of any GPU hardware?

Comment: When you draw the wave-form you only need to draw one slice-per-screen-pixel. Just calculate how many samples you need to skip to select one per pixel.

Comment: @andrew double buffering for sure and drawing in separate thread from read and processing. Downsampling is to reduce signal sampling rate. Minimax for optimal results but for a first approximation to give impression of responsiveness you may just skip samples. Then work in chunks, this will reduce lag (X for first third, x*2 for second third and so on). Processing may be done with one thread per channel. Finally fast fast drawing code (give a chance to direct 2d on Windows)

Comment: Reduce sampling rate: do you need 20M samples on 1k pixels window? No, with 2k samples you have enough to represent the wave (less on first stage). For each pixel one sample for maximum and one for minimum.

Comment: Seriously people, stop worrying about the GUI drawing code :-). If you must know, I'm using https://github.com/abainbridge/deadfrog-lib, which I wrote. On my 2.3GHz i3, I get 218 FPS drawing a 5 channel waveform filling a 1700x1000 section of the window. It's GDI based on Windows and is double buffered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading Peter Stock's answer, I've come up with the following scheme. I think it will allow display calculation about 500 times faster than the naive scheme and shouldn't add any noticeable cost to inserts or deletes. The memory overhead is less than 1%.

The sound data will be allocated in blocks of 131072 samples, so that inserts and deletes don't require the entire sound to be reallocated and copied. When the sound is first loaded, each block will be completely filled (except probably the last one). Inserts and deletes will lead to a kind of fragmentation. For simplicity, I will arrange for the start of each block to always contain valid sample data, and any gaps will be at the end of the block.

Each block has two look-up tables associated with it, one for max values and one for min. Each item in the look-up tables corresponds to 1024 samples.

The diagram below shows how to calculate the max value for one pixel width of the display. It shows a few blocks relevant to the calculation. It assumes there is no "fragmentation".

[image: Display calculation for one pixel width (no fragmentation)]

After an insert, the situation is slightly more complicated. Two blocks now have invalid regions at their ends. There are entries in the max look-up table that now corresponds to a part-empty region of samples. The value for these entries are found by just taking the max of the samples that *are* present.

[image: Display calculation for one pixel width (with fragmentation)]

Comment: My implementation of this is https://github.com/abainbridge/sound_shovel/blob/4c442871ad530748dac9444f3f9b23ace6275ba7/src/main.cpp. At this stage it just creates a mono buffer of 2 hours of 48 kHz 16-bit audio. Calculating the display buffer for an 800 pixel fully-zoomed out view takes ~2ms on my i3-6100U based machine. However, it is simple to understand at this stage. I'll post again if/when I make it more fully featured.

Comment: I have now added WAV loading and interactive scrolling and zooming. There's a win32 binary on GitHub now too - https://github.com/abainbridge/sound_shovel/releases

Answer (score 2):

When the zoom is at the point where you have multiple samples per pixel it is not worth calculating accurately the mean sample value for each pixel. The user can't align the GUI tooling accurately at that level of zoom so it's no benefit. The user just needs a qualitative view.

I would just select one sample per screen pixel for the window area, skipping over the unnecessary samples.

Something like this *completely untested* code:

```
std::vector<double> samples(1024*1024); // [-1.0 < s < 1.0]

int window_x = 1024; // window size in pixels
int window_y = 768; // window size in pixels

// visit every window pixel
for(int x = 0; x < window_x; ++x)
{
    // select relevant sample for the current screen pixel x
    double s = samples[(x * samples.size()) / window_x];

    int y = (window_y / 2) * s; // get y size for sample value

    // draw sample point/line at coordinate (x, f(y))
    gd.draw_line(x, (window_y / 2) - y, x, (window_y / 2) + y);
}
```

Obviously you also need to account for window scrolling etc...

Comment: I think this is similar to what Adriano says in the comments to my question. There's definitely some value to this. With your scheme, I worry about the pathological case when the sound is sine wave with a frequency of samples.size() / window_x. Then each iteration of the loop will get the same value for s. I think Adriano suggests gradually improving this approximation by considering more and more samples per pixel as a background process.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge Well a pure sine wave from a generator might also continue to exhibit the same effect when considering the neighboring samples because they would be identical in each case. So they would average the same. At least in the way I have chosen to display the wave as vertical lines, the display will continue to be correct in your scenario. However it would have trouble representing very low frequencies. I suppose you could introduce random jitter to precisely which sample is chosen from among its neighbors? Or to the progression of the variable that iterates screen pixel locations?

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge yes, I'd go with something like this for the first pass (but don't do it in memory - it's almost useless - do not even _read_ from disk unneeded samples!) Does it look good (see your screenshots) with an artifical signal? No, of course not but it's good enough with _true_ signal and... **then do a proper decimation** (minimax) in background using all samples. If perceived speed isn't enough you then may do decimation in blocks to present (and keep UI responsive). It's _effect_ I almost always see for sound editor programs.

Comment: Of course you may do better (also to handle a sinus wave) but it will then become much more complicate because you have to optimize your I/O, cache and perform as much as possible asynchronously (again to give the _impression_ it's instantaneous.

Comment: @Adriano - I agree that most real world signals will look better with this approximation than the sine wave does. And your point about not even loading the samples from disk is interesting. However, I think I can achieve the performance I want and show perfect results, with fairly simple code. I'll post my solution shortly once I've drawn some diagrams. I will have to load all the samples into RAM though.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge 5 GB in RAM? You may keep a fairly low-res version in RAM (to be used for _overview_ and 2X) but more than that you're going to use little bit too much resources, also processing/downsampling should be done in chunks because of this. I'd be happy to see simple code for this _problem_, I'll keep an eye on this

Comment: @Adriano - I think using 5 GB will be fine if the machine has 8 GB of RAM. It seems a bit pointless optimizing more than this since people editing samples that size will surely have that much RAM. Maybe you think it wasteful, but what else is RAM for? It saves a lot of programming effort. I've posted my code to GitHub, see the link in my answer's comment. It's not production quality at all, just a brain dump before I forget what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the mip-mapping technique from graphics, trading using more memory for faster speed?

If you have 32 samples, maintain a cache of zoomed out x2, x4, x8, ... Storing this data will take the same space again as the original data (16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 samples).

A visual guide, with `.` representing a stored data point (min/max sample value) and `_` the samples covered by the previous `.`:

```
1st level: ................
2nd level: ._._._._._._._._
3rd level: .___.___.___.___
4th level: ._______._______
5th level: ._______________
```

Then just query the appropriate level mip-map for the zoom level.

Yes, you would have to re-create the mip-map cache (or part of it) when you insert/remove samples.

But maybe the memory usage makes this not appropriate for you?

---

**Edit**

If adding and removing is a frequent operation and makes re-calculation of the cache undesirable (and you want accurate downsampling over intervals rather than just at single points), then you could change the mip-mapping approach to store the data aligned to the local min/max sample points rather than a time-based grid.

Using `--------|--------` to denote a local min/max over an interval, here's a pictorial representation:

```
                             --------|--------
   --------|--------
                   --------|--------
                                     --------|--
------|--------
                                     .
           .                        . .
.     .   . .   .          .       .   .     .
 . ... . .   . . .   . .. . .     .     .   . .
  .     .     .   . . .  .   .   .       . .   .
                   .          . .         .
                               .
--------|--------
           --------|--------
                                  --------|-----
                       --------|--------
```

Then adding and removing only requires a re-calculation of the immediate local areas at the start and end of the added/removed section.

You'll probably want to index the local min/max values, so you don't need to do a lot of searching. A more complex scheme to implement - maybe not worth it for you?

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking along these lines. Given that scanning every sample every frame is only a few hundred times to slow, I'm tempted to only use one mip-map level. Where one item in the array represents something like 2^15 samples (Since I expect the largest sounds I need to support will be around 2^30 samples). The memory usage of such a scheme is tiny. My question is, is there any way to avoid recalculating the entire mip-map after every insert/delete. I can think of some ways to make it so you only need to re-calc 1/4 on average, but that still seems poor to me.

Comment: Your edited solution looks about right to me. I don't understand quite how you decide where to start and end the range of each "local max" search. I've posted an answer similar to yours but where the "local max" is calculated for every fixed 1024 sample range, aligned on a 1024 sample boundary. Does this seem reasonable to you? Or am I missing a trick?

Comment: I was only speculating - I have no experience of actually having done this so I don't have much more to offer! Yes, there's some details to fill in: to have fixed-length 'local max' regions or not? to allow them to overlap or not? I my my example I centered them on the local max sample, although looking at the rightmost max, it's not actually a max sample - just the max sample that's not already covered my a 'local max' value. I'd assign them starting from the largest un-covered sample and keep going until all samples are covered by local max values.

Comment: I've just been doing some calculations. If you are halving the resolution at each mip-map "step", you will require ~98% _more_ memory total. However, if you divide the resolution by 4 instead, the additional memory cost drastically jumps down, to ~39%. Going further, dividing by 8 will yield ~14% more memory cost total. So in this case, you might experiment with the division amount, as the memory efficiency scales. I've been getting reliable 60 fps visualizations even in JavaScript (although there's a _lot_ of GPU accelerated coating used in my case).